# Why sympy cannot correctly determine identity of simple sqrt expressions?

Tags: sympy

[image]

Even if it correctly determine the inequalities of both sides, it cannot determine the identity.

```py
from sympy import *
assert not 2 * sqrt(2 - sqrt(3)) == -sqrt(2) + sqrt(6)
assert 2 * sqrt(2 - sqrt(3)) <= -sqrt(2) + sqrt(6)
assert 2 * sqrt(2 - sqrt(3)) >= -sqrt(2) + sqrt(6)

assert not 2 * sqrt(2 - sqrt(3)) == sqrt(8 - 4 * sqrt(3))
assert 2 * sqrt(2 - sqrt(3)) <= sqrt(8 - 4 * sqrt(3))
assert 2 * sqrt(2 - sqrt(3)) >= sqrt(8 - 4 * sqrt(3))
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: If you are seeing rational numbers not equal to each other in the way you expect, I would assume it is a rounding error

Comment: both lhs and rhs are symbolic. I don't think there is rounding. And `simplify(lhs - rhs)` can produce `0` correctly.

Comment: a==b tests structural equality not mathematical equality. https://docs.sympy.org/latest/explanation/gotchas.html#double-equals-signs

Comment: Thanks! @OscarBenjamin, your comment perfectly solves my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is, as commented by @OscarBenjamin, "a==b tests structural equality not mathematical equality."

> The equality operator (`==`) tests whether expressions have identical form, not whether they are mathematically equivalent.
>
> https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Faq#why-does-sympy-say-that-two-equal-expressions-are-unequal

> Double equals signs (`==`) are used to test equality. However, this tests expressions exactly, not symbolically.
>
> https://docs.sympy.org/latest/explanation/gotchas.html#double-equals-signs

Except to use `simplify(lhs - rhs)` and check if the expression reduces to 0, `Eq(lhs, rhs)` can be used.

```py
from sympy import *
assert Eq(2 * sqrt(2 - sqrt(3)), -sqrt(2) + sqrt(6))
```

> This class is not the same as the == operator. The == operator tests for exact structural equality between two expressions; this class compares expressions mathematically.
>
> https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.relational.Equality

See also: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/gotchas.html#equals-signs

P.S. `.equals` tests if two expressions are equal by evaluating them numerically at random points.

Comment: `Eq` will do more than `==` but it will not try too hard. If you want to try harder, use `a.equals(b)`. For example, `Eq(cos(1)**2+sin(1)**2,1)` is unevaluated while `(cos(1)**2+sin(1)**2().equals(1)` evaluates to True. Standard disclaimer about any routine proving that A = B for arbitrary A and B is apropos.

Comment: Yes, given any method, there always exists some equations can't be determined. `Eq` won't give `False` if it cannot determine the truth value, that is enough.

Comment: @smichr `equals` tests if two expressions are equal by evaluating them numerically at random points. There can be false negative or false positive. However, `Eq` will remain unevaluated if sympy cannot determine the truth value.